# C# Windows Mobile SIP InputPanel: How to resize my TextBox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Using the **Soft Input Panel** (`SIP`) to enter text on my **C# WinMobile CF 2.0** application.

There is a textbox at the bottom that I want to enlarge whenever the `SIP` is pressed.

The `SIP` is called correctly whenever the `TextBox` receives focus, but I can't seem to get the `TextBox` to grow enough to see the text.

The `TextBox` is docked to the bottom.

I've placed breakpoints in my code, and the `SIP_EnabledChanged` routine is being hit and the `txtNote.Size` is being changed ...but the size of my `TextBox` does not change on the display.

Why?

```
using Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms;

int startH = txtNote.Size.Height;
// (In the designer):
this.inputPanel1.EnabledChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.SIP_EnabledChanged);

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  inputPanel1.Enabled = false;
  startH = txtNote.Size.Height;
}

void SIP_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SuspendLayout();
  int height = inputPanel1.Enabled ? startH + 80 : startH;
  txtNote.Size = new Size(txtNote.Size.Width, height);
  ResumeLayout();
}
```

[image: TextBox displayed]  [image: SIP displayed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer on MSDN [>> HERE <<](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/de6d03d1-5000-449b-a943-604b85da4e7c/) yesterday that I was able to modify to work.

The key, apparently, is to set the `Bounds`, not the `Size` or the `Location`.

Here is what I went with:

```
int startY;

void Form1() : Form {
  InitializeComponent();
  startY = txtNote.Location.Y; // only set here.
}
// Method below fires whenever the Soft Input Panel changes
void SIP_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int locationY = startY;
  if (inputPanel1.Enabled) {
    locationY -= inputPanel1.Bounds.Height;
  }
  txtNote.SuspendLayout();
  // setting the Bounds was the key to getting this to work!
  txtNote.Bounds = new Rectangle(
    txtNote.Location.X,
    locationY,
    txtNote.Size.Width,
    txtNote.Size.Height
  );
  txtNote.ResumeLayout();
  txtNote.Refresh();
}
```

I hope that posting the solution helps someone, one day.

Answer (score 1):

If it's docked, and not anchored is the first thing that could be off here.  I'm skeptical that you really want to change the size of the text box.  I usually handle changes in the input panel but moving the entire form up (- direction) by the height of height of the SIP, rather than resize my controls.  This form looks a little different though, and perhaps you have a single entry control?  If that's the case I'd be sure it's the first control in the z order and just position it above the SIP when it's displayed.